# Match partial query with mongoose regex between two collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have two collection 
I only included the fields in question.
List Collection

```
 ListSchema = new Schema({
  location: {
    zip: Number,
    city: String,
    province: String,
    address: String
  }
})
```

Addon Collection

```
AddonSchema = new Schema({

  extra_loc: {
    type: Array
  }
})
```

I want to find if a given partial string is present to either `location fields` or to the `extra_loc` and return the `List` that matched. My current code only matches the `location fields`. it gives me the desired output if it finds a match. But with valid query that should match an item in `extra_loc` returns empty array.

mongoose version: 5.7.1,

```
 List.aggregate([
        {
            $lookup:
            {
                from: "addons",
                localField: "location",
                foreignField: "extra_loc",
                as: "extras"
            }
        },
        {
            $match: {
                $or: [
                    {
                        "location.zip": {
                            $regex: query,
                            '$options': 'i'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "location.city": {
                            $regex: query,
                            '$options': 'i'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "location.province": {
                            $regex: query,
                            '$options': 'i'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "location.address": {
                            $regex: query,
                            '$options': 'i'
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        'extras.extra_loc': {
                            $in: [query]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }

    ], (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.json(err)
        }

        List.populate(data, { path: 'feature', select: 'geometry type' }, (err, populatedData) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.json(err)
            }

            if (populatedData) {
                res.json(populatedData)
            }
        })
    });
```

I expect the code to give me a match if my query matches an item in `extra_loc`.

Comment: i've lost faith to mankind